# How to integrate mongo with play, spark and scala?

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I am using play framework 2.2.0 and configured mongo for play+ scala using salat.

I integrated spark with above by adding following to build.sbt

```
 "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.1.0",
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.2.3",
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % "2.2.3",
"org.mongodb" % "mongo-hadoop-core" % "1.3.0",
"org.apache.spark"  %% "spark-mllib" % "1.1.0"
```

Now I want to write a code which will calculate linear regression of data using spark and mongo. But I dont know how to query mongo from mongo.

Here is my simple class that do not contains mongo part.

```
import com.mongodb.DBObject
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
import com.mongodb.casbah.commons.MongoDBObject
import com.mongodb.casbah.commons.ValidBSONType.BasicDBObject
import com.mongodb.util.JSON
import play.Play
import play.Logger
import play.api.libs.json.{JsValue, Json}

import scala.collection.JavaConversions.{collectionAsScalaIterable => asScala}
import play.Logger
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration


def apply(customerId: String)= {

   val data = List((1416668402352, 10),
      (1415684102290, 20),
      (1415684402210, 30),
      (1415684702188, 15),
      (1415684702780, 25),
      (1415685001845, 40),
      (1415685301846, 100),
      (1415685602110, 35),
      (1415685603483, 50),
      (1416668101756, 29),
      (1415685901549, 95),
      (1415686201903, 18),
      (1415686502076, 24),
      (1415686502765, 90),
      (1415686801514, 32))
    val numIterations = 20
//    val model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(list.toArray, numIterations)

    val config = new Configuration()
  }
```

Here I have given data that is in mongo collection with name 'activity'.
I want to fetch data from activity collection and calculate linear regression of it.

How to query to mongo from scala+play+spark??

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but for integrating mongo and scala, there is a reactivemongo project (which we are using in out Play + Scala project)

http://reactivemongo.org/

It's non blocking, and you have mimics mongoDB functions.

```
  import reactivemongo.api._
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  // gets an instance of the driver
  // (creates an actor system)
  val driver = new MongoDriver
  val connection = driver.connection(List("localhost"))

  // Gets a reference to the database "plugin"
  val db = connection("plugin")

  // Gets a reference to the collection "acoll"
  // By default, you get a BSONCollection.
  val collection = db("acoll")

  val values: Enumerator = collection.find(Json.obj()).cursor.enumerate()
```

It works with Enumerators, but you can downgrade it to synchronous calls, if you need, but I would not recommend that

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Enumerators

Answer (score 0):

If you are using play and you want an ORM tool, you can try Salat + salat-play-plugin [Play-salat](https://github.com/shayanlinux/play-salat)

I was using play 2.4 but it's 2.5 + now , and this plugin was written in 2.3, you may need to figure out how to make it work on you project. But it works on 2.4, you've got my promise.

I am not so sure you do you need to query mongo by scala+play+spark, if you mean query mongo by spark, you can use a [mongo connector](https://github.com/Stratio/Spark-MongoDB) to do that, it's pretty simple. If you means you need to invoke/query spark by API from play, I haven't do that before, sorry about that.